# Android Studio, Gradle: Initialize Build never ends

Tags: android-studio, build, gradle

Please help, I am going crazy with this problem i am having with Gradle.

When using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 Gradle continuesly sit's there saying '**Initialize Build**'

I have heard it can take a while to complete, so i left it 7 hours overnight with still no joy.

This is stopping me from building in the IDE.

I have cleared the .gradle folder from users directory and run Android Studio as admin and still not working

Oh, typing **gradlew build** on the command line works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I got into the same problems with IntelliJ 14 & 15. Never ending initialize build. Maybe it's not a problem of IDE, but gradle setup. Look where you have .gradle folder ( usually in your home directory. I recommend to delete everything there, especially cache.

- would be good to see how your build looks like
- what version of gradle you have 
  etc.